# Looking to extend inner classes in Groovy

Tags: groovy, inner-classes

I'm looking to extend an inner class in Groovy, it's part of a mix-in pattern that needs a groovy calculation method to be added after class construction but natively use the accessors of the main class.   Works in Java, not so much in Groovy.  Help appreciated.

p.s. realize that `with { }` groovy construct may be an alternative...   trying to get this to work

**Base class (in Java):**

```
public class JavaClass {

    private String foo = "Foo";
    private Calculation calculation;

    public JavaClass() {
        calculation = new Calculation();
    }

    public JavaClass(Calculation calculation) {
        this.calculation = calculation;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return calculation.getBar();
    }

    public class Calculation {
        public String getBar() {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**I create a Groovy implementation:** (I know it's a bit hokey, bear with me)

```
class GroovyCalculationClass extends JavaClass {
    public GroovyCalculationClass() { }

    public Calculation getCalculation() {
        return new Calculation();
    }

    public class Calculation extends JavaClass.Calculation {
        public String getBar() {
            return getFoo() + "Bar";
        }
    }
}
```

**Run this test:**

```
class TestCalculation {

    @Test
    public void testCalculation() {

        JavaClass javaClass = new JavaClass(
            new GroovyCalculationClass().getCalculation());
        Assert.assertEquals("FooBar", javaClass.getBar());
    }


}
```

And get this:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at com.modelshop.datacore.generator.GroovyCalculationClass$Calculation.(GroovyCalculationClass.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
>       at com.modelshop.datacore.generator.GroovyCalculationClass.getCalculation(GroovyCalculationClass.groovy:12)
>       at com.modelshop.datacore.generator.GroovyCalculationClass$getCalculation.call(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>       at com.modelshop.datacore.generator.TestCalculation.testCalculation(TestCalculation.groovy:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Replace GroovyCalculationClass with identical JavaCalculationClass and everything works.

Comment: Your code is really messy; strange combinations of inner classes and inheritance - it might "work" in java, but perhaps not the way you think it does. I would really try to rethink this mixin pattern. What are you trying to achieve? Are you locked in with regards to the Java superclass and inner class implementations?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Groovy, it works if both classes are Groovy

Comment: To 'messy' comment - not sure it's messy, but agree it's convoluted.  The reason is it is an illustration of code that will be generated from metadata.  The pattern is needed to avoid recompiling the data classes when the groovy language 'mixin' is recompiled, allowing a fast and tight typed core with flexible calculation decorators to be updated in rea-ltime from the UI.